# How to fix cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL statement in which I'm inserting(copying) data from one table to another, I have 2 primary keys "Code" and "Name". Now when selecting the values from the other table and insert to my table it results in an error:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'KTable1_PR'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table1'. The duplicate key value is
>   (00003106)".

For the two primary keys I'm using replicate combined left and row_number: pasted below.
Any ideas on how I could work around this issue?

```
 INSERT INTO [Table1] 
  (  
 Code,  
 Name,
  )
   (SELECT 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 8) + LEFT((SELECT CAST ( MAX(Code) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Table2].[U_PosNo] )  FROM [Table1]), 8),8)), 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 30) + LEFT((SELECT CAST ( MAX(Name) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Table2].[U_PosNo] )  FROM [Table1]), 30),30)),
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are not repeated? Have you tried running your `SELECT` statement alone, without `INSERT`? What does it return?

Comment: yes i did and the last entry is 00003105, so  I'm really not sure why it doesn't want to increment the next entry in a sequence

Comment: any one with any suggestion on how i could do an increment on the said columns?

Comment: can you upload both tables CREATE sql with some data of source table?

Comment: do you need further clarification?